# How would I replace my ascii arrow with an Image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Hi I am trying to replace my ascii arrow with an image of an arrow to show that there is a submenu. I know how to put an image on the left of the text but cannot see how to put an image on the right. I have tried googling this and am out of luck.

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
                    EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/PrizeRedemption.aspx" Text="Prize Issuance">
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Issue Bounty Prizes" NavigateUrl="~/IssueBountyPrize.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Administration" 
                            Value="Administration" Selectable="False">
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Users" Value="Users" NavigateUrl="~/Admin.aspx?mode=users"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Prizes" Value="Prizes" NavigateUrl="~/Admin.aspx?mode=prizes"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Tournaments  >" Value="Tournaments" NavigateUrl="~/IssuePrizes.aspx">
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Tournament Templates"  Value="Tournament Templates" NavigateUrl="~/TournamentTemplates.aspx">
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                            </asp:MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably add a class to the `MenuItem`. Then use CSS `background-position` to position your image in the correct location.

Read [CSS background-position documentation](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-position) for more information.